# Running through variables in for loop

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, dynamic

I'm new to Python, but I use it to process data. I've got a large amount of data stored as float arrays:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

I want to run similar processing for each data file. I was thinking of using a for loop:

```
for i in range(1,4):
```

I would like to then multiply the three data files by two, but I'm not sure how to continue afterwards. I imagine it would look like his:

```
for i in range(1,4):
     data_i=data_i*2
```

Thank you.

Comment: `call the three data files`?!?!?!

Comment: For example, I would like to multiply all the data files by 2.
So data1*2, data2*2, data3*2.

Comment: If you want to change the variable names it is impossible, at least without altering the python processor

Answer (score 1):

You could make a two-dimensional array, meaning you put your float arrays inside another array.

Your situation right now would look like this:

```
data1 = [12, 2, 5]
data2 = [2, 4, 8]
data3 = [3, 0, 1]
```

By putting your arrays inside another array by doing this:

```
datax = [data1, data2, data3]
```

Your new situation would look like this:

```
datax = [[12, 2, 5], [2, 4, 8], [3, 0, 1]]
```

Now we can loop over the new `datax` array and perform an action on it's *elements*, `data1`, `data2` and `data3`.

Something along the lines of:

```
datax = [[12, 2, 5], [2, 4, 8], [3, 0, 1]]

for sub_array in datax:
    perform_action(sub_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store the data in e.g. list

```
data_list = [data1, data2, data3]

for i, data in enumerate(data_list):
    some_fancy_stuff
    data_list[i] = data * 2
```

Some explanation - enumerate will literally enumerate the items of the list with index `i` and also assigns `data_list[i]` to variable `data`. Than you can do whatever you want with `data` and its index `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Python comprehension instead of loops, here is an example to illustrate it:

```py
>>> a1 = [1,2,3]
>>> a2 = [4,5,6]
>>> a3 = [7,8,9]
>>> A = [a1, a2, a3]
>>>
>>> print [[x*2 for x in a] for a in A]
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18]]
>>>
```

Let me explain it also.

The following construction is called *comprehension*:

```
a = [x*2 for x in X]
```

It produces an array (as you could see the brackets `[ ]`) of processed values (in the example value multiplication by two) from array `X`. It's as if we wrote:

```py
a = []
for x in X:
    a.append(x*2)
```

but in more concise way.
In your situation we used two comprehension one in one:

```py
[x*2 for x in a]
```

and:

```py
[ [....] for a in A]
```

So it's the same as if we did:

```py
result = []
for a in A:
    for x in a:
        result.append(x*2)
```

but in more concise way again.

If you asked about variable names modification, so it is not possible in the Python without altering the language processor. But I guess you don't need it in that task at all.

Comment: Only use `map` or a list comprehension if you actually need the resulting list. If you are simply using it for the side effect of calling `some_func` on each element of `A`, use an explicit for loop instead.